# Cannot load backend 'WXAgg' which requires the 'wx' interactive framework, as 'headless' is currently running

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython

I have installed wxpython and matplotlib with conda

matplotlib version is 3.3.2

my system is a centos 7

```
$ python
Python 3.7.9 (default, Aug 31 2020, 12:42:55) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import wx
>>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.use("WXagg")
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/pascale/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2336, in <module>
    switch_backend(rcParams["backend"])
  File "/home/pascale/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 287, in switch_backend
    newbackend, required_framework, current_framework))
ImportError: Cannot load backend 'WXAgg' which requires the 'wx' interactive framework, as 'headless' is currently running
```

What is missing ?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

This problem was fixed after a yum install of gstreamer and its plugins and SDL.